# Orchard ImageGallery Module: Missing Orchard.Media

Tags: orchardcms

I have installed Orchard 1.7 via the Web Platform Installer. When I add the ImageGallery module or the PrettyGallery modules they install but the features do not enable. If I locate the entries in the Features list both of them report 'Missing: Orchard.Media'. Orchard.Media.dll is present in:

- \Modules\Orchard.Fields\bin
- \App_Data\Dependencies

Has anybody else had this issue with these modules?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because Orchard.Media is not the default Media module anymore. It's one of the deprecated modules now, download the source code and see the references there.

Comment: And you should probably nag the authors of those modules so that they provide 1.7 versions of their work.

Comment: Bertrand's ZenGallery module do (I'm using it in a lot of projects)